# Is it possible to generate JWT token with certain role in keycloak?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, keycloak

I am wondering that is it possible to generate JWT token with certain role in keycloak.
After user login successfully, user select one of his/her roles then I regenerate jwt token with
only specified role. It is important because I have microservices and authorization in this services require role policy which role comes from jwt.